# Can I create a patch for unversioned files with Tortoise SVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn, patch

I'd like to create a patch reflecting changes to an unversioned file. I have both "before change" and "after change" versions and Tortoise Diff is happy to compare them. Can I also make a patch reflecting those changes with Tortoise SVN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have TortoiseSVN installed and if I select to show unversioned files, I can select Diff from the context menu. This will open WinMerge, where I can choose "Tools"->"Generate Patch" to create a Diff-file.

**Update:** Just tested without WinMerge. If you choose two files, Diff open TortoiseMerge, where you can choose "Edit"->"Create unified diff file".

Answer (score 5):

1. In Windows Explorer right click on your svn working copy directory.
2. Select TortoiseSvn -> Create Patch.
3. Select 'Show Unversioned Files' checkbox.
4. Select the files to include and press OK.

(this was with TortoiseSVN 1.6.5, Build 16974 - 32 Bit)

Comment: This will only create a patch againts current svn, not a patch between the two unversioned files, or not?